# Getting a bad decrypt error in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using this snippet to extend the `String` class in Rails:

```
require 'openssl'

class String
  def encrypt(key)
    cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher.new('DES-EDE3-CBC').encrypt
    key = cipher.random_key
    cipher.key = key
    s = cipher.update(self) + cipher.final

    s.unpack('H*')[0].upcase
  end

  def decrypt(key)
    cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher.new('DES-EDE3-CBC').decrypt
    key = cipher.random_key
    cipher.key = key
    s = [self].pack("H*").unpack("C*").pack("c*")

    cipher.update(s) + cipher.final
  end
end
```

However when de-crypting the string I get the "Bad decrypt error":

```
puts plain = 'confidential'           # confidential
puts key = 'secret'                   # secret
puts cipher = plain.encrypt(key)      # 5C6D4C5FAFFCF09F271E01C5A132BE89

puts cipher.decrypt(key)              # BAD DECRYPT
```

I tried adding padding like this to the decrypt action (Similar SO question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12508502/bad-decrypt-error-in-ruby)):

```
cipher.padding = 0
```

The error goes away but I am getting gibberish instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if you are passing key (`secret`) to the encrypt & decrypt functions, you are redefining key again with the below mentioned code.

```
key = cipher.random_key
```

You should be using same key for both encrypt & decrypt.
Try the below code snippet:

```
require 'openssl'

class String
  def encrypt(key)
    cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher.new('DES-EDE3-CBC').encrypt
    cipher.key = (Digest::SHA1.hexdigest key)[0..23]
    s = cipher.update(self) + cipher.final

    s.unpack('H*')[0].upcase
  end

  def decrypt(key)
    cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher.new('DES-EDE3-CBC').decrypt
    cipher.key = (Digest::SHA1.hexdigest key)[0..23]
    s = [self].pack("H*").unpack("C*").pack("c*")

    cipher.update(s) + cipher.final
  end
end



puts plain = 'confidential'           # confidential
puts key = 'secret'                   # secret
puts cipher = plain.encrypt(key)      # 5C6D4C5FAFFCF09F271E01C5A132BE89


puts cipher.decrypt(key)              # confidential
```